# What are the statues at the Eternity gate?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, character-identification, thor-love-and-thunder

At the Eternity gate there are a few statues lining the chamber. I assume they are all known Marvel characters. Who were all the ones we saw?

[image: Screenshot at 1:30:50]

[image: Cropped screenshot at 1:29:52]

(click to enlarge)

Comment: "I assume there are all known Marvel Characters" - bold assumption...

Comment: @PeterNielsen that's been the case with every background statue / carving before

Comment: Considering the attention to detail Marvel usually shows, I'd be astonished if these were simply random.

Comment: "Known" doesn't have to be "known at this point of the MCU".

Answer (score 19, accepted):

1. A Celestial - the [One Above All](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/One_Above_All_(Celestial)) based on the triangles
2. [The Watcher](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/The_Watcher)
3. [The Living Tribunal](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Living_Tribunal)
4. [Eternity](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Eternity)
5. [Death](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Death)
6. [Eon](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Eon_(Earth-616))
7. [Infinity](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Infinity_(Earth-616))

Comment: The Celestial is Eson, not Arishem. https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Eson_the_Searcher

Comment: @KlausÆ.Mogensen I couldn't find a screenshot of it yet, so hard to confirm. We're going to need a guide to Celestial head identification for all the 6-eyed ones.

Comment: I was going to say that the statue looked nothing like Arishem, but it turns out that the MCU Arishem looks a lot like Eson (MCU or comics), So I guess that both are possible options until we get a decent screenshot.

Comment: I assumed it was Arishem, as he is the Prime Celestial with a major role in *Eternals*, while Eson was only briefly shown but never named in *Guardians of the Galaxy*.

Comment: @KlausÆ.Mogensen with the better screenshots, the chest definitely looks more like Eson than Arishem.

Comment: I can't think about them without thinking about the Beyonder for some strange reasons.

Comment: @KlausÆ.Mogensen although Eson's head is smooth, while Arishem has the "handles"...

Comment: [This wiki](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/One_Above_All) says it's the One Above All, but the source provided makes no mention of it.